# Flutter check if Apple user exists in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I need to check if apple user exists. Using flutter sign_in_with_apple package and connecting with firebase. Is there a direct way to check from firebase whether apple user exists or not, so I can redirect them to another page.

Comment: if your user gets registered using apple login you can check in firebase object like user !- null, if user exists or not, then you can redirect in your page. Check this https://medium.com/swlh/integrate-sign-in-with-apple-with-firebase-authentication-db0953b383c4#:~:text=To%20do%20so%2C%20go%20to,inside%20the%20'Authentication'%20section.&text=Look%20for%20'Apple'%20in%20the,and%20then%20click%20'Save'.